# Dependency Injection for Date Object

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

I am try to DI a Date object

here's the code for the xml file

```
<bean id="date" class="java.util.Date"/>
<bean id="obj"   class="com.Person.Implementor" autowire="byName">
    <property name="username"><value>Abc</value></property>
    <property name="password"><value>password</value></property>
</bean>
```

Here's the class:

```
package com.Person;
import java.util.Date;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
public class Implementor {

String username;
String password;

Date date;

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

@Autowired
public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Implementor [username=" + username + ", password=" + password
            + ", date=" + date + "]";
}


public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

}
```

But it doesnt seem to work, the Date reference seems to have the NULL value while printing, it works fine for custom created classes tough

Update: Got a reply for Spring support form:
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?127017-Dependancy-Injection-for-Date-Object&p=414519#post414519

"This is by Spring design. Spring does not do auto-wiring for "simple" properties, e.g. primitives, Strings and Date. But i don't see a good reason for you to auto-wire bean with Date type. "

Comment: What is the reasoning behind injecting a Date?

Comment: If you're ok with the spring support answer, then post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: Got a reply for Spring support form: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?127017-Dependancy-Injection-for-Date-Object&p=414519#post414519

"This is by Spring design. Spring does not do auto-wiring for "simple" properties, e.g. primitives, Strings and Date. But i don't see a good reason for you to auto-wire bean with Date type. "

Answer (score 0):

Is there more to your spring config file? Since you'll need `<context:annotation-config />` to activate the post-processors which do the autowiring.

It seems odd to specify two of the dependencies in XML and then use autowiring for a third. In this case it would be more consistent to do something like:

```
<bean id="obj"   class="com.Person.Implementor" autowire="byName">
    <property name="username"><value>Abc</value></property>
    <property name="password"><value>password</value></property>
    <property name="date"><ref bean = "date"/></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Just got a reply for Spring support forums, "This is by Spring design. Spring does not do auto-wiring for "simple" properties, e.g. primitives, Strings and Date. But i don't see a good reason for you to auto-wire bean with Date type. ", thanks for your help anyways